# Using SplideJS arrows outside of splide

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, splidejs

I'm building this bootstrap page (mobile view) which has a splide.  for the design, it's way easier to have the arrows outside of the splide itself rather than trying to move the arrows into position.
But as the arrows are outside of the splide, then they're not working - and im not sure what events need to be triggered to get it to slide.

- Note - while the site is mostly bootstrap 5, it also has some tailwinds classes like padding\margins (you might notice this in the code)

Here's what the page looks like;
[image]

```
<!--  Mobile Display start -->
            <div class="row d-md-none">
                <div class="col-12 bg-white">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <img class="" style="width:75%;" src="Assets/CEDA-Dots_1.png" alt="ceda_dots">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <img class="-mt-4 mx-auto" style="height:75%;" src="Assets/Qotes.png" alt="quotes">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10 pl-4 pb-2 -mt-8">
                            <p class="text-2xl font-medium pl-5">CEDA Learning - delivering value for organisations and individuals</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 ml-4" style="position:relative; height: 25px;">
                            <div class="splide__arrows">
                                <button class="splide__arrow splide__arrow--prev" style="background-color:#ffffff;" type="button" aria-controls="mobile-testim-carousel-track" aria-label="Go to last slide">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 40 40" width="40" height="40">
                                        <path d="m15.5 0.932-4.3 4.38 14.5 14.6-14.5 14.5 4.3 4.4 14.6-14.6 4.4-4.3-4.4-4.4-14.6-14.6z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                                <button class="splide__arrow splide__arrow--next" style="background-color:#ffffff;" type="button" aria-controls="mobile-testim-carousel-track" aria-label="Next slide">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 40 40" width="40" height="40">
                                        <path d="m15.5 0.932-4.3 4.38 14.5 14.6-14.5 14.5 4.3 4.4 14.6-14.6 4.4-4.3-4.4-4.4-14.6-14.6z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-4" style="background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffffff 50%, #e11837 50%)">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="splide ml:0" id="mobile-testim-carousel">
                                <div class="splide__track pt-4 pb-4">
                                    <ul class="splide__list">
                                        <li class="splide__slide splide_width">
                                            <div class="container">
                                                <div class="row p-2 bg-white">
                                                    <div class="col-2 p-0 pt-2">
                                                        <img src="Assets/Portrait/10_Portrait.png" class="w-20">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-10 text-black text-base ps-2 pt-2">
                                                        <p class="text-sm font-bold">Anne Finlay | Manager Coordination </p>
                                                        <p class="text-sm font-medium">WA Dept. Primary industries & Regional Development</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-12 pt-3">
                                                        <p class="text-xs font-normal">I’ve worked in the public sector, across several agencies, for over 25 years. During this time, I have had several touch points with economic concepts without any real understanding of the broader economics framework. This online course filled in those gaps for me in a way that sustained my interest and allowed me to incorporate the learning into my existing workload. While going through the course, I had many ‘aha’ moments which cumulated in solid foundation in economics concepts.</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="splide__slide splide_width">
                                            <div class="container">
                                                <div class="row p-2 bg-white">
                                                    <div class="col-2 p-0 pt-2">
                                                        <img src="Assets/Portrait/10_Portrait.png" class="w-20">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-10 text-black text-base ps-2 pt-2">
                                                        <p class="text-sm font-bold">Anne Finlay | Manager Coordination </p>
                                                        <p class="text-sm font-medium">WA Dept. Primary industries & Regional Development</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-12 pt-3">
                                                        <p class="text-xs font-normal">I’ve worked in the public sector, across several agencies, for over 25 years. During this time, I have had several touch points with economic concepts without any real understanding of the broader economics framework. This online course filled in those gaps for me in a way that sustained my interest and allowed me to incorporate the learning into my existing workload. While going through the course, I had many ‘aha’ moments which cumulated in solid foundation in economics concepts.</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and of course the JS:

```
<script>
new Splide('#mobile-testim-carousel', {type:'loop', arrows: false, rewind: true, pagination: false, autoplay: false, perPage: 1, gap:'1em'}).mount(); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also disable default navigation buttons (aka "arrows") and attach events to your custom buttons directly.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  let splide = new Splide('#image-carousel', {
    // hide default buttons
    arrows: false,
    type: 'loop',
  }).mount();

  //attach events to custom buttons
  btnNext.addEventListener('click', e => {
    splide.go('+1')
  })

  btnPrev.addEventListener('click', e => {
    splide.go('-1')
  })

});
```

```css
.splide {
  width: 50vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.splide__slide img {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/js/splide.min.js
"></script>
<link href="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/css/splide.min.css
" rel="stylesheet">

<p><button id="btnPrev">prev</button> <button id="btnNext">next</button></p>

<section id="image-carousel" class="splide" aria-label="Beautiful Images">
  <div class="splide__track">
    <ul class="splide__list">
      <li class="splide__slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="">
      </li>
      <li class="splide__slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/236/200/300" alt="">
      </li>
      <li class="splide__slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/235/200/300" alt="">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

See also the official [API documentation](https://splidejs.com/guides/apis/) and about [customizing arrows](https://splidejs.com/guides/arrows/)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably more elegant ways to do it, but i just ended up including arrows within the splide, setting them to `display:none`, and then adding some JQuery so that the buttons outside of splide perform click function on the hidden buttons.

```
<!--  Mobile Display start -->
            <div class="row d-md-none">
                <div class="col-12 bg-white">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <img class="" style="width:75%;" src="Assets/CEDA-Dots_1.png" alt="ceda_dots">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <img class="-mt-4 mx-auto" style="height:75%;" src="Assets/Qotes.png" alt="quotes">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10 pl-4 pb-2 -mt-8">
                            <p class="text-2xl font-medium pl-5">CEDA Learning - delivering value for organisations and individuals</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 ml-4 mt-1" style="position:relative; height: 25px;">
                            <div class="splide__arrows">
                                <button class="splide__arrow splide__arrow--prev" id="mobile-test-prev" style="background-color:#ffffff;" type="button" aria-controls="testim-carousel-track" aria-label="Go to last slide">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 40 40" width="40" height="40">
                                        <path d="m15.5 0.932-4.3 4.38 14.5 14.6-14.5 14.5 4.3 4.4 14.6-14.6 4.4-4.3-4.4-4.4-14.6-14.6z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                                <button class="splide__arrow splide__arrow--next" id="mobile-test-next"style="background-color:#ffffff;" type="button" aria-controls="testim-carousel-track" aria-label="Next slide">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 40 40" width="40" height="40">
                                        <path d="m15.5 0.932-4.3 4.38 14.5 14.6-14.5 14.5 4.3 4.4 14.6-14.6 4.4-4.3-4.4-4.4-14.6-14.6z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-4" style="background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffffff 50%, #e11837 50%)">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="splide ml:0 md:-ml-40" id="mobile-testim-carousel">
                                <div class="splide__arrows">
                                    <button class="splide__arrow splide__arrow--prev" id="hide-mobile-prev" style="display:none;" type="button" aria-controls="testim-carousel-track" aria-label="Go to last slide">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 40 40" width="40" height="40">
                                            <path d="m15.5 0.932-4.3 4.38 14.5 14.6-14.5 14.5 4.3 4.4 14.6-14.6 4.4-4.3-4.4-4.4-14.6-14.6z"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="splide__arrow splide__arrow--next" id="hide-mobile-next" style="display:none;" type="button" aria-controls="testim-carousel-track" aria-label="Next slide">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 40 40" width="40" height="40">
                                            <path d="m15.5 0.932-4.3 4.38 14.5 14.6-14.5 14.5 4.3 4.4 14.6-14.6 4.4-4.3-4.4-4.4-14.6-14.6z"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="splide__track pt-4 pb-4">
                                    <ul class="splide__list">
                                        <li class="splide__slide splide_width">
                                            <div class="container">
                                                <div class="row p-2 bg-white">
                                                    <div class="col-2 p-0 pt-2">
                                                        <img src="Assets/Portrait/10_Portrait.png" class="w-20">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-10 text-black text-base ps-2 pt-2">
                                                        <p class="text-sm font-bold">Anne Finlay | Manager Coordination </p>
                                                        <p class="text-sm font-medium">WA Dept. Primary industries & Regional Development</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-12 pt-3">
                                                        <p class="text-xs font-normal">I’ve worked in the public sector, across several agencies, for over 25 years. During this time, I have had several touch points with economic concepts without any real understanding of the broader economics framework. This online course filled in those gaps for me in a way that sustained my interest and allowed me to incorporate the learning into my existing workload. While going through the course, I had many ‘aha’ moments which cumulated in solid foundation in economics concepts.</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="splide__slide splide_width">
                                            <div class="container">
                                                <div class="row p-2 bg-white">
                                                    <div class="col-2 p-0 pt-2">
                                                        <img src="Assets/Portrait/10_Portrait.png" class="w-20">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-10 text-black text-base ps-2 pt-2">
                                                        <p class="text-sm font-bold">Anne Finlay | Manager Coordination </p>
                                                        <p class="text-sm font-medium">WA Dept. Primary industries & Regional Development</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-12 pt-3">
                                                        <p class="text-xs font-normal">I’ve worked in the public sector, across several agencies, for over 25 years. During this time, I have had several touch points with economic concepts without any real understanding of the broader economics framework. This online course filled in those gaps for me in a way that sustained my interest and allowed me to incorporate the learning into my existing workload. While going through the course, I had many ‘aha’ moments which cumulated in solid foundation in economics concepts.</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and the JS...

```
 new Splide('#mobile-testim-carousel', {type:'loop', arrows: true, rewind: true, pagination: false, autoplay: false, perPage: 1, gap:'1em'}).mount(); 

$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mobile-test-prev').click(function() {
                $('#hide-mobile-prev').click();
            });

            $('#mobile-test-next').click(function() {
                $('#hide-mobile-next').click();
            });
        })
```