# Custom Arrow Buttons Not Working with SplideJS Slider in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, splidejs

I'm trying to integrate custom arrow buttons for navigation in a SplideJS slider within my PHP code. However, the custom buttons don't seem to trigger the slide movement. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
<!-- PHP and HTML structure -->
<div class="splide w-100 notes-slider">
    <!-- ... other slider elements ... -->
    <div class="s_btn-wr d-flex">
        <button id="btnPrev" class="splide__arrows--prev splide_prev">
            <!-- SVG for left arrow -->
        </button>
        <button id="btnNext" class="splide__arrows--next splide_next">
            <!-- SVG for right arrow -->
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    waitForSplide(() => {
        var splide = new Splide('.notes-slider', {
            // ... Splide options ...
        }).mount();

        document.getElementById('btnNext').addEventListener('click', function () {
            splide.go('>');
            console.log('next');
        });

        document.getElementById('btnPrev').addEventListener('click', function () {
            splide.go('<');
            console.log('prev');
        });

    }, '.notes-slider');
</script>
```

Problem: When I click on the custom arrow buttons (btnNext and btnPrev), nothing happens. The console doesn't logs 'next' or 'prev' correctly.

I'm not sure if the issue is with how I'm referencing the Splide instance or with the event listeners. How can I fix this so that the custom buttons control the slider as expected?

Comment: Where have you defined `waitForSplide(()` ? It's not a standard splide.js method. you could use a generic `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { ...` event to mount your slider. See also ['Using SplideJS arrows outside of splide'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76420603/using-splidejs-arrows-outside-of-splide/76434885#76434885). Check your dev tools console for errors.

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery, also i have defined waitForSplide in my head, `function waitForSplide(callback, element) {
 if (splideLoaded && document.querySelector(element)) {
  callback();
 } else {
  setTimeout(() => waitForSplide(callback, element), 100);
 }
}
`

Comment: I Don‘t use any jquery either. I have the suspicion your splide initialization doesn‘t work as you‘re waiting for an undefined event/State. Does your solider react on any Inputs (touch, keyboard etc.)? Please add a running snippet to your description.